# Find current grade with curve [Python]

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that will calculate my current grade in a class with different categories of grades with different weightings. So far I have:

```
import math as m
total_grade = 0

c = int(input('How many curves?'))
for n in range(1,(c+1)):
    print(n)
    curve'{}'.format(n) = float(input('What is curve #{} as a decimal?'.format(n)))
    grade'{}'.format(n) = list(input('What is the {}nth set of grades as a list?'.format(n)))
    partial_grade = curve'{}'.format(n) * m.mean(grade'{}'.format(n))
    total_grade += partial_grade
```

But I'm not sure how to make `n` number of curves and sets of curves and lists of grades. For example lets say there are 2 categories of grades: tests and homework. tests have a 70% curve and homework is a 30% curve. I want to input first the .70 and .30 and then for tests enter a list of grades such as [.85,.95,.92] and homework in the same manner: [.95,.85,.84,1.0]. Then I want to find the average of each category and multiply it by the curve then add that to the total.

Comment: Your question is very vague; you need to define what you are trying to accomplish much more clearly (maybe give an example with actual values). It looks like maybe binning numeric scores into letter grades with defined cut-off values?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I just added an example

Comment: You keep using "curve" but I still have no idea what you mean by it.

Comment: "Grading on a curve" is a colloquialism (at least in the US) that refers to scaling the normal grading system (A: 90-100%, B: 80-89%, etc.) relative to the overall performance of the class. The term comes from the description of a bell curve. I think original "curve" grading awarded the top 10% of students an A, the next 10% a B, and so on. There is no strict definition, though, AFAIK. @greenthumbtack will have to give a better description for this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a weighted sum of averages:

```
tests are   `p1`%          p1 * avg(tests)
homework is `p2`%          p2 * avg(homework)
...
cat_N    is `pN`%          pN * avg(cat_N)
           =====          ================
            100.%          final score
```

so

```
# this code assumes Python 3
def make_weighted_sum_fn(weights):
    """
    Given a list of weights, return a function which
      calculates a final weighted score
    """
    weights = list(weights)
    len_ = len(weights)
    def weighted_sum_fn(values):
        values = list(values)
        assert len(values) == len_
        return sum(w * v for w, v in zip(weights, values))
    return weighted_sum_fn

def average(lst):
    """
    Find the mean value of a list

    eg
        average([1., 2., 6.])   # => 3.

    If the list is empty, return 0.
    """
    if lst:
        return sum(lst) / len(lst)
    else:
        return 0.

def get_curves_fn(N):
    weights = [float(input("What is curve #{}? ".format(n))) for n in range(1, N + 1)]
    return make_weighted_sum_fn(weights)

def get_cat_scores(cat):
    return [
        float(f)
        for f in input("What is the {}th set of grades (space-delimited)? ".format(cat)).split()
    ]

def get_categories_scores(num_categories):
    return [get_cat_scores(cat) for cat in range(1, num_categories + 1)]

def main():
    N   = int(input("How many curves? "))
    cfn = get_curves_fn(N)

    while True:
        name = input("\nEnter student name (or Enter to quit): ").strip()
        if name:
            categories = get_categories_scores(N)
            final = cfn(average(cat) for cat in categories)
            print("{}'s final mark is {}".format(name, final))
        else:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
How many curves? 2
What is curve #1? 0.7
What is curve #2? 0.3

Enter student name (or Enter to quit): Jake
What is the 1th set of grades (space-delimited)? 65 75 85
What is the 2th set of grades (space-delimited)? 90 80
Jake's final mark is 78.0

Enter student name (or Enter to quit): Melissa
What is the 1th set of grades (space-delimited)? 88 84 82
What is the 2th set of grades (space-delimited)? 75 78
Melissa's final mark is 82.21666666666667

Enter student name (or Enter to quit):
```